# How do I split a string with multiple separators in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

How do I split a string as below, and add the record to the database? The order of the string is not the same user inputs.

string "Key3:352,Key1:353,Key2:380,Key4:381,Key5:181"

Result should be on records
fieldname key: 3 .. etc
fieldname ID: 352 .. etc

Comment: why is this marked as javascript?

Comment: One simple split will not do the trick here.  You will have to do it in 3 steps.  One to identify "Key", one for the number before the colon, and one for the number after the colon.

Comment: I can't make any sense of the sentence "The order of the string is not the same user inputs". I'm also not entirely sure what it is that you're trying to write to the database. Could you give us a better idea of how the database is structured? As in, given your sample input string, *exactly* what should go in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the question, this should work:

```
var parser =function(toParse) {
    var table = toParse.split(',');
    for (var subString in table) {
        var subString2 = subString.split(':');

        var key = subString2[0].replace('Key', '');
        var ID = subString2[1];
    }
}
```